# Action line questions in screenplay format

Tags: screenwriting

Is it EVER okay to say I’m the action line “a beat”

Are parentheticals ONLY for the way the speaker talks

Can you say:

> Bathsheba
>   I love you
>   (she pulls him to her)
>   let’s just try

Answer (score 5):

It's generally bad practice to put action in parentheticals. And best to avoid them as they can quickly become a crutch and are often unnecessary. In the example you listed, you could write it like this:

```
                               BATHSHEBA
                     I love you.

           She pulls him in.

                               BATHSHEBA
                     Let's just try.
```

The action has much more impact when it's not wedged in between lines. It also breaks up the script more to create a sense of forward movement.